# Extending ActiveModel::Serializer with custom attributes method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I am trying to create my own `attributes` method called `secure_attributes` where I pass it an array of attributes and the minimum level the authorized user needs to be to view those attributes.  I pass the current level of the authorized user as an instance_option.  I'd like to extend the Serializer class so I can use this method in multiple serializers, but Im having issues.

This is what i have so far:

in `config/initializers/secure_attributes.rb`

```
module ActiveModel
  class Serializer
    def self.secure_attributes(attributes={}, minimum_level)

      attributes.delete_if {|attr| attr == :attribute_name } unless has_access?(minimum_level)

      attributes.each_with_object({}) do |name, hash|
        unless self.class._fragmented
          hash[name] = send(name)
        else
          hash[name] = self.class._fragmented.public_send(name)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then in the individual serializer I have things like this:

`secure_attributes([:id, :name, :password_hint], :guest)`

and then

```
  def has_access?(minimum_level=nil)
    return false unless minimum_level
    return true # based on a bunch of logic...
  end
```

But obviously secure_attributes cannot see the `has_access?` method and if I put `has_access` inside the Serializer class, it cannot access the instance_options.

Any idea how I can accomplish what I need?

Comment: what do you mean with `instance_option`?

Comment: Your problem is: You try to access an instance method inside a class method.

You need to define self.has_access?(minimum_level=nil) instead of has_access? to make your code working. Maybe you want to explain more about your use case - then I can propose some more detailed solution. What method call do you want to overwrite in functionality with your logic?

Comment: I think you will have to just cache the secure_attributes in a class level instance variable Hash and write a hook for the method you want to use / overwrite it (checking this class instance variable). So the logic you want to put into the class method - has to be moved into instance level.

Comment: After I looked deeper into ActiveModel::Serializer - I think you want to overwrite initialize.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to do following - but I still do not get your real purpose, since you never did anything with the attributes but calling them:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class JoshsSerializer < Serializer
    class << self
      def secure_attributes(attributes={}, minimum_level)
        @secure_attributes = attributes
        @minimum_level = minimum_level
      end
      attr_reader :minimum_level, :secure_attributes
    end

    def initialize(attr, options)
      super attr, options
      secure_attributes = self.class.secure_attributes.dup
      secure_attributes.delete :attribute_name unless has_access?(self.class.minimum_level)
      secure_attributes.each_with_object({}) do |name, hash|
      if self.class._fragmented
        hash[name] = self.class._fragmented.public_send(name)
      else
        hash[name] = send(name)
      end
    end

    def has_access?(minimum_level=nil)
      return false unless minimum_level
      return true # based on a bunch of logic...
    end
  end
end
```